# Best way to read file contents of a file and set to empty string if exception happen

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
try:
    content = open("/tmp/out").read()
except:
    content = ""
```

Can I go any shorter or more elegant than this? I've to do it for more than one files so I want something more short.

Is writing function the only shorter way to do it?

What I actually want is this but I want to concat `""` if there is any exception

```
lines = (open("/var/log/log.1").read() + open("/var/log/log").read()).split("\n")
```

Comment: Don't use a blanket except handler; catch specific exceptions only.

Comment: This concerns me too, but I think that reading all the file at once is not a good idea, especially if the files are big in size. @MartijnPieters could you write a solution to this? I am interested in a good way to do this too.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: Sure, you want to deal with files line-by-line if at all possible; but that depends on what the OP is trying to read from the files.. A function that tries filenames in succession and returns the first one that opens successfully is easy enough to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will monkey patch out `open` for another *open* that creates a FakeFile that always returns a *"empty"* string if `open` throws an `IOException``.

Whilst it's more code than you'd really want to write for the problem at hand, it does mean that you have a reusable context manager for faking `open` if the need arises again *(probably twice in the next decade)*

```
with monkey_patched_open():
     ...
```

Actual code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from contextlib import contextmanager
from StringIO import StringIO
################################################################################
class FakeFile(StringIO):
    def __init__(self):
        StringIO.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0

    def read(self, n=-1):
        return "<empty#1>"

    def readlines(self, sizehint = 0):
        return ["<empty#2>"]

    def next(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            self.count += 1
            return "<empty#3>"
        else:
            raise StopIteration
################################################################################
@contextmanager
def monkey_patched_open():
    global open
    old_open = open

    def new_fake_open(filename, mode="r"):
        try:
            fh = old_open(filename, mode)
        except IOError:
            fh = FakeFile()
        return fh

    open = new_fake_open

    try:
        yield
    finally:
        open = old_open

################################################################################
with monkey_patched_open():
    for line in open("NOSUCHFILE"):
        print "NOSUCHFILE->", line
    print "Other", open("MISSING").read()
    print "OK", open(__file__).read()[:30]
```

Running the above gives:

```
NOSUCHFILE-> <empty#3>
Other <empty#1>
OK #!/usr/bin/env python
from co
```

I left in the "empty" strings just to show what was happening.

`StringIO` would have sufficed just to read it once but I thought the OP was looking to keep reading from file, hence the need for FakeFile - unless someone knows of a better mechanism.

I know some see monkey patching as the act of a scoundrel.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll have to write something like

```
def get_contents(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            return f.read()
    except EnvironmentError:
        return ''


lines = (get_contents('/var/log/log.1')
         + get_contents('/var/log/log')).split('\n')
```

**NlightNFotis** raises a valid point, if the files are big, you don't want to do this. Maybe you'd write a line generator that accepts a list of filenames:

```
def get_lines(filenames):
    for fname in filenames:
        try:
           with open(fname) as f:
               for line in f:
                   yield line
        except EnvironmentError:
            continue


...

for line in get_lines(["/var/log/log.1", "/var/log/log"]):
    do_stuff(line)
```

Another way is to use the standard `fileinput.FileInput` class (thanks, J.F. Sebastian):

```
import fileinput

def eat_errors(f, mode):
    try:
        return open(f, mode)
    except IOError:
        return open(os.devnull)

for line in fileinput.FileInput(["/var/log/log.1", "/var/log/log"], openhook=eat_errors):
    do_stuff(line)
```

Comment: I believe that the `+` operator when used to **concatenate strings** *is extremelly inefficient*, and the `.join()` method of the strings should be used instead, especially when handling great (in length) strings. *I am not so sure about what I said however, and need somebody to correct me or agree with me.*

Comment: `+` is inefficient when there are many small strings. When there are two big ones, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: you could use `fileinput.input(filenames, openhook=eat_errors)` instead of `get_lines()`

Comment: Thanks, today I learned about `fileinput`. I don't like the module global state though.

Comment: And you still have to write the openhook which must return a valid file.

Comment: You could use `fileinput.FileInput()` to avoid global state. `def eat_errors(f, m): try: return open(f, m) except IOError: return open(os.devnull, m)`

Comment: OK, thank you, added it to my answer. I still don't like how `fileinput` is written :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, but it's probably not the best:

```
import os

def chk_file(filename):
    if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        with open(filename) as f:
            return f.readlines()


if __name__=="__main__":
    print chk_file("foobar.txt") #populated file
    print chk_file("bar.txt") #empty file
    print chk_file("spock.txt") #populated
```

It works.  You can wrap it with your try-except, if you want.

Answer (score -1):

You could define a function to catch errors:

```
from itertools import chain

def readlines(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            return file.readlines() # or just `file` to return an iterator 
    except EnvironmentError:
        return []

files = (readlines(name) for name in ["/var/log/1", "/var/log/2"])
lines = list(chain.from_iterable(files))
```